# Unitary time-evolution operator on position and momentum eigenstate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, time-evolution

What will be the result when the unitary time-evolution operator acts on position or momentum eigenstate $$\hat{U}(t,t_0) |p\rangle$$ or $$\hat{U}(t,t_0) |x\rangle$$ **I think the result will be such**: $$\hat{U}(t,t_0) |x\rangle=f(t)|x\rangle$$ where $f(t)$ is a complex function of time such that its modulus $|f(t)\lvert=1$.
**Is this right?**

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Hamiltonian of a system as
$$U(t)=e^{-iHt/\hbar}$$

To know $$U(t)|x\rangle \ \ \ \mathrm{or} \ \ \ U(t)|p\rangle$$

One must know
$$H|x\rangle \ \ \ \ \mathrm{or} \ \ \ \ H|p\rangle $$

For example, suppose a free particle
$$H=\frac{P^2}{2m}$$
$$U(t)|p\rangle=e^{-iHt/\hbar}|p\rangle=e^{-ip^2/2m\hbar}|p\rangle$$

---

Edit: The last line in question
$$U(t)|x\rangle=f(t)|x\rangle$$
so that matrix element of $U(t)$ in position basis
$$U(x,t;x')=\langle x'|U(t)|x\rangle = f(t)\langle x'|x\rangle=f(t)\delta(x-x')$$
which is indeed wrong! (Think why yourself)

Comment: Yes it depends on the Hamiltonian but keeping in mind that it is unitary in nature and the position and momentum eigenkets actually are basis vectors in their respective vector spaces I think that my last line is perhaps right.

Comment: No, it's not. See the example I have given.

Comment: See the edit. It concludes why you are wrong. Though I didn't know what's your reasoning to do that?